Stack Dify Portainer , traefik ,no se ve en el navegador
quiero hacer la siguiente consultam a ver si alguien  me puede dar una mano,
Estoy intentando desplegar Dify en un servidor VPS con Portainer en una red Docker Swarm.
Tengo muchas otras funcionando lo mas  bien, entre ellas postgres y redis, que las requiere aqui.
Todo parece funcionar, los logs de cada contenedor lo reflejan, la base de datos weavite se ve en el navegador accediendo con la ip y :8080.Cree una base de datos en postgres dify, el resto de base de datos, si hay que hacerlo, aun no lo hice,pero deberia poder accederse al frontend. Los puertos esta abiertos. Si alguien puede ver si es problema del codigo, o de los pasos para hacerlo funcionar. Muchas gracias
version: '3.7'
services:
  api:
    image: langgenius/dify-api:latest
    environment:
      MODE: api
      LOG_LEVEL: INFO
      SECRET_KEY: sk-9f73s3ljTXVcMT3Blb3ljTqtsKiGHXVcMT3BlbkFJLK7U
      INIT_PASSWORD: ''
      CONSOLE_API_URL: ''
      SERVICE_API_URL: ''
      APP_WEB_URL: ''
      FILES_URL: ''
      MIGRATION_ENABLED: 'true'
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: difyai123456
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: dify
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_USERNAME: ''
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ''
      REDIS_USE_SSL: 'false'
      REDIS_DB: 0
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/1
      WEB_API_CORS_ALLOW_ORIGINS: '*'
      CONSOLE_CORS_ALLOW_ORIGINS: '*'
      STORAGE_TYPE: s3
      STORAGE_LOCAL_PATH: storage
      S3_ENDPOINT: 'https://minio.midominio.com'
      S3_BUCKET_NAME: 'difyai'
      S3_ACCESS_KEY: 'PBSN1mjFe8dujusVUMSD'
      S3_SECRET_KEY: 'UEcn5jiYToTh4VvaP2UdshsjGjRAvWbJxoc6eClP7'
      S3_REGION: 'us-east-1'
      VECTOR_STORE: weaviate
      WEAVIATE_ENDPOINT: http://weaviate:8080
      WEAVIATE_API_KEY: WVF5YThaHlkYwhGUSmCRgsX3tD5ngdN8pkih
      MAIL_TYPE: smtp
      SMTP_SERVER: smtp.zoho.com
      SMTP_PORT: 587
      SMTP_USERNAME: soporte@midominio.com
      SMTP_PASSWORD: difyai123456
      SMTP_USE_TLS: 'false'
      MAIL_DEFAULT_SEND_FROM: 'Dify <soporte@midominio.com>'
      RESEND_API_KEY: ''
      RESEND_API_URL: https://api.resend.com
      SENTRY_DSN: ''
      SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE: 1.0
      SENTRY_PROFILES_SAMPLE_RATE: 1.0
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - app_storage:/app/api/storage      
    ports:
      - '5001:5001'
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify-api.rule=Host(`difyai.midominio.com`) && (PathPrefix(`/console/api`) || PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/v1`) || PathPrefix(`/files`))" # Troque pelo seu dominio ou subdominio
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify-api.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify-api.entrypoints=web,websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify-api.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify-api.service=dify-api"
      - "traefik.http.services.dify-api.loadbalancer.server.port=5001"
      - "traefik.docker.network=mi_red"
  worker:
    image: langgenius/dify-api:latest
    environment:
      MODE: worker
      LOG_LEVEL: INFO
      SECRET_KEY: sk-9f73s3ljTXVcMT3Blb3ljTqtsKiGHXVcMT3BlbkFJLK7U
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: difyai123456
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: dify
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_USERNAME: ''
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ''
      REDIS_DB: 0
      REDIS_USE_SSL: 'false'
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/1
      STORAGE_TYPE: s3
      STORAGE_LOCAL_PATH: storage
      S3_ENDPOINT: 'https://minio.midominio.com'
      S3_BUCKET_NAME: 'difyai'
      S3_ACCESS_KEY: 'PBSN1mjFe8OUkusVUMSD'
      S3_SECRET_KEY: 'UEcn5jiYToTh4VvaP2U4tw1GjRAvWbJxoc6eClP7'
      S3_REGION: 'us-east-1'
      VECTOR_STORE: weaviate
      WEAVIATE_ENDPOINT: http://weaviate:8080
      WEAVIATE_API_KEY: WVF5YThaHlkYwhGUSmCRgsX3tD5ngdN8pkih
      MAIL_TYPE: smtp
      SMTP_SERVER: smtp.zoho.com
      SMTP_PORT: 587
      SMTP_USERNAME: soporte@midominio.com
      SMTP_PASSWORD: difyai123456
      SMTP_USE_TLS: 'false'
      MAIL_DEFAULT_SEND_FROM: 'Dify <soporte@midominio.com>'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - app_storage:/app/worker/storage

  web:
    image: langgenius/dify-web:latest
    environment:
      EDITION: SELF_HOSTED
      CONSOLE_API_URL: ''
      APP_API_URL: 'https://difyai.midominio.com' 
      SENTRY_DSN: ''
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # SSL
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify.rule=Host(`difyai.midominio.com`)" # Troque pelo seu dominio ou subdominio
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify.entrypoints=web,websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dify.service=dify"
      - "traefik.http.services.dify.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=portainer_default"
  
  weaviate:
    image: semitechnologies/weaviate:1.19.0
    volumes:
      - weaviate:/var/lib/weaviate
    environment:
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'false'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'none'
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
      AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_ENABLED: 'true'
      AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_ALLOWED_KEYS: 'WVF5YThaHlkYwhGUSmCRgsX3tD5ngdN8pkih'
      AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_USERS: 'hello@dify.ai'
      AUTHORIZATION_ADMINLIST_ENABLED: 'true'
      AUTHORIZATION_ADMINLIST_USERS: 'hello@dify.ai'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

volumes:
  app_storage:
    external: true
    name: app_storage 
  weaviate:
    external: true
    name: weaviate

networks:
  default:
    name: mi_red
    external: true

